# Redefine properties with arguments

Tags: c#, properties

I define a class property algorithm as follows:

```
public InputParametersProperty InputParameters { get; set; }

public class InputParametersProperty
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get { return inputParameters[name]; }
        set
        {
            if (inputParameters == null)
                inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            else
                inputParameters.Add(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

From another class I want to use the property of the form:

```
algorithm.InputParameters["populationSize"] = 100;
```

But I get the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: In your constructor for `algorithm`, do you set `InputParameters` to a new `InputParametersProperty` object, or is it staying as null?

Answer (score 3):

You're never instantiating the InputParameters property to anything. That's why you're gettin `NullReferenceException`.

Change:

```
public InputParametersProperty InputParameters { get; set; }
```

to:

```
private InputParametersProperty _inputParameters;
public InputParametersProperty InputParameters
{
    get
    {
        return _inputparameters ?? (_inputparameters = new InputParametersProperty()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: He could just do it in the constructor.

Comment: @romoku Which would then lead to problems if he ever inherits from the class and doesn't call the `base()` or something. My approach is more OOP-friendly.

Comment: In C# the derived type will automatically call its base parameterless constructor.

Comment: @romoku unless the property is `virtual` and overriden somewhere in the inheritance chain. That could lead to problems. What if the derived type (or the base type) doesn't have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: @romoku also, what if the `InputParametersProperty` instance eats 12313080320 mb of memory? my approach lazy-loads it when it is first accessed (if it ever is). yours loads it when the class containing the property is instantiated.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The constructor provides a default implementation of the class, so all properties that should be accessible after creation are better served in the constructor. There can be cases when lazy loading is preferable especially when the property is needed on demand (like using MVVM in WPF).

Comment: @Romoku I agree. Those are 2 different ways of doing it that should be considered depending on the actual situation.

Comment: @HighCore Keep YANGNI in mind.  Don't over-engineer every little type.  Odds are this type shouldn't ever be extended (it could be made `sealed` to make this intent explicit) that avoids all of those issues.  Designing a class that can be properly extended is a lot of work; and it's work that is very rarely actually needed.  It's better to just make it clear that it shouldn't happen except for the few rare cases where inheritance is true needed/expected.

Comment: @servy you're right. I guess I got used to this method simply because I press `Ctrl+Enter` and ReSharper creates the backing field and all that stuff XD